# PowerShell command Get-ADDomainController randomly failing

Tags: powershell

We are calling Get_ADDomainController from C# code to get all the DCs in a forest-

```
Get-ADDomainController -Discover -ForceDiscover -DomainName "abc.xyz.com"
```

This command works most of the times, but sometimes it does fail with below error-

```
Get-ADDomainController : The format of the specified domain name is invalid
```

Can someone please let me know what might be going wrong when the command does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to go through the following Links. They have mentioned all the possibilities. So it is not easy to pick any one randomly.

I believe your domain contains pre-created read-only domain controller (RODC) accounts.

[Link 1 - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2737424/-format-of-the-specified-domain-name-is-invalid-error-when-you-try-to)

[Link 2 - Programmatically Join](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27039821/The-format-of-the-specified-domain-name-is-invalid-error-in-Powershell-Add-Computer.html)

If Windows cannot determine the user or computer name. (The format of the specified domain name is invalid. ). Group Policy processing aborted.

Try this: [Link 3 - GP Aborting](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/122508-userenv-1053-the-format-of-the-specified-domain-name-is-invalid-on-2003-dc) and then [GP Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/937535/event-id-1053-is-logged-when-you-use-the-gpupdate-force-command--or-yo)

Hope it helps.

Ideally this should move to ServerVault, but still can be considered in SO cause coding is involved.